# How to add an auth_id with webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authorization, webapp2

I use the auth module from webapp2 and I want to know how to add an auth_id like 'facebook:fbuserid12121212' and add that to the list of auth_id:s for a user. But I see no function from the API that allows me to do this. Could you please tell me how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Might be worthwhile to move your update / answer to an actual answer (so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered). Thanks for sorting this out :)

Comment: @jgeewax I've moved the answer to the answers section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer that the OP found. I'm copying it here so that this question will not be unanswered:

[This was answered in the google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webapp2/Ui5FEFVnyIY), the function I was looking for is user.auth_ids.append and the code I use now to make use of it is:

```
@user_required
def post(self, **kwargs):
    email = self.request.POST.get('email')
    auser = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
    userid = auser['user_id']
    user = auth_models.User.get_by_id(auser['user_id'])
    existing_user = auth_models.User.get_by_auth_id(email)

    if existing_user is not None:
        # You need to handle duplicates. 
        # Maybe you merge the users? Maybe you return an error?
        pass

    # Test the uniqueness of the auth_id. We must do this to 
    # be consistent with User.user_create()
    unique = '{0}.auth_id:{1}'.format(auth_models.__class__.__name__, email)

    if auth_models.User.unique_model.create(unique):
        # Append email to the auth_ids list
        user.auth_ids.append(email)
        user.put()
        return "Email updated"
    else:
        return 'some error'
```

Comment: How about retrieving the auth_id for a user?